# How to set JavaFX CheckBox value in a TableView Column?

Tags: checkbox, javafx, tableview, tablecell, tablecolumn

I am trying to get 'Active' value from 'Information' class and set it to TableView Column as Checkbox, so user can edit. I have following in my controller:

```
activeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Information, Boolean>("Active"));
            final Callback<TableColumn<Information, Boolean>, TableCell<Information, Boolean>> cellFactory = CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(activeColumn);
            activeColumn.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Information, Boolean>, TableCell<Information, Boolean>>() {
                @Override
                public TableCell<Information, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Information, Boolean> column) {
                    TableCell<Information, Boolean> cell = cellFactory.call(column);
                    cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    return cell ;
                }
            });
            activeColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
            activeColumn.setEditable(true);
```

Here is my 'Information' class where I'm getting Active value as true/false

```
public Information(Hashtable information) {
    :::

    String strActive = cvtStr(information.get("Active"));
            if (strActive.equals("1"))
                this.active = true;
            else if (strActive.equals("0"))
                this.active = false;
}
 public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
```

When I run it I'm not getting the Checkbox checked where 'Active' is true. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Would any one tell me where am I doing wrong? Or is there any other ways to get this done?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaFX properties in your model class:

```
public class Information {

    private final BooleanProperty active = new SimpleBooleanProperty();

    public Information(Hashtable information) {

        // ...

        String strActive = cvtStr(information.get("Active"));
        if (strActive.equals("1"))
            setActive(true);
        else if (strActive.equals("0"))
            setActive(false);
    }

    public BooleanProperty activeProperty() {
        return active ;
    }

    public final boolean isActive() {
        return activeProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setActive(boolean active) {
        activeProperty().set(active);
    }

    // ...

}
```

Note that you have an error in your cell value factory (which you inexplicably set twice): it should be

```
activeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Information, Boolean>("active"));
```

Better still would be

```
activeColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().activeProperty());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried. Doesn't work. Would you please tell me how to use activeProperty() in the controller? Many many thanks to consider answering.

Comment: @SadequerRahman Oh, you have an error in your cell value factory. Updated the answer. The `PropertyValueFactory` implicitly uses `activeProperty()` (as long as you get the name correct); it's better to use an explicit implementation of cell value factory anyway. If that still doesn't work I suggest you create a [MCVE] and edit your question to include it.

Comment: I wanna thank you one more time. It's perfectly worked as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I discovered that it is much simpler to make the property of the data object a type CheckBox rather than boolean. Then using the property in a tableview is MUCH easier and more straightforward.

Comment: plain wrong - you __must not__ have Nodes in the data class

Comment: Can you elaborate?